# Suggestions for two-choice game played in ladder graph

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I was just working on counting all the possible Nash Equilibrium solutions for a two-choice game played on a ladder graph (I got my results and all that for a generic number of players).

And I was wondering if you'd have any suggestions for related papers/books to see if I can find a practical application or any ideas to generalise it in graph theory. Thanks!